# TSQL - Loop over column to query other table

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm stuck with the following task:

1. via Excel the user types in an **ID** then clicks a button (macro) to trigger SP or function
2. this **ID** usually "returns" more than one row
3. from this result I need the values of a single column (**LookupNumber**) in order to use those values to query or join another view. Looping required?
4. as a result I want to join the initial ID request table with the result of the other queried table.

In below image, the first table holds the ID the user wants to search.
The second table should be queried by the **LookupNumber** values that were retrieved from table **A**.

The third table shows the desired output:
[image]

The problem I have is how do I loop (if needed) through the LookupNumber once the search ID has been passed? I don't know what methods I should use for this task.

Because sqlfiddle doesn't seem to work, I put the tables from above screenshot in this [link](http://rextester.com/PKKTT40209)

Hopefully you can give me some ideas how to solve this.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here, you produced your 'desired output' with SQL code in your linked example...?  What is it you want us to do?

Comment: the question is how to loop over the LookupNumber column that is returned in the first query.

Comment: SQL doesn't really 'loop' over records in the manner you are suggesting, nor have you explained the purpose of this 'looping'.  What is your desired output, if not what you already have in your question?  Either you have further requirements you have not explained or you have your desired output already and don't need any help.

Comment: So you want a set of rows with two `ID` columns, two `Project` columns, ... . Might that cause some problems? Are you asking how to perform an `INNER JOIN` on `LookupNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table2 t2
inner join (
    select ID, Subject, Project, LookupNumber
    from table1
    where id = <entered id>
) t1 on t1.LookupNumber = t2.LookupNumber
```